# Can't connect to mysql, have tried a lot of things

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I've read a ton of threads and solutions, I'm not purposely trying to make yet *another* one of these posts.

Now that thats out of the way

if i run this in my local osx folder (with web sharing on), i get a could not connect error:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");

if (!$db) {
die('Could not connect' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

yet when i go to terminal and run the following it works fine:

```
mysql -u root -h 'localhost' -p
password<enter>

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1030
Server version: 5.5.25a MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

i have updated php.ini to point to `/tmp/mysql.sock` as well

Comment: have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just starting out and are using PHP5, you should not use `mysql_connect`, but instead [`mysqli_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) *(use of the mysql extension is [discouraged](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect))*.

Check [`connect_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php) to get more information about why the connection is failing.

*(Example taken from the above doc)*

```
<?php
$mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'THE DB NAME');

// Works as of PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: it says 'no such file or directory'. im basically trying to install phpmyadmin locallly, and it keeps giving error 2002. when i try it this way (to eliminate phpyadmin complete as a variable of whats wrong..), i get this. "no such file or directory"

Comment: I have a feeling the warning is a bit more elaborate than that, but I am going to guess you need to change `mysqli.default_socket`. For me on OSX, I had to change this from `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` to `/tmp/mysql.sock`. You would make the equivalent change to your `mysql.default_socket` path once you get it right with the test script in my answer above.

Comment: youre right mang. i ran phpinfo and it still shows the old path... but i changed this in /etc/php.ini... is there somewhere else its located in OSX? (the php.ini file that is)

Comment: PS. I changed it and i did restart apache

Comment: `php -i | grep Loaded` will show you the path of the loaded `php.ini`

Comment: Okay i see... there were multiple occurances of that. i though there was only one

Answer (score 0):

Try to display your php configuration with a `phpinfo();`, you might learn a lot from that.

Also, check the port number used by MySQL, I've seen many example where it wasn't standard on OSX installation.

Comment: how do i check the port number?

Comment: well wtf! it says my socket isnt /tmp/mysql.sock like i set it in php.ini.... and i did restart apache

Comment: On phpinfo there are two lines :
mysql.default_port or mysqli.default_port depending of your connection setup.